# How to enter text in initcap in Textfield?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app when i click on textfield keypad appears,

I have taken the "Name Phone Pad" keypad from properties,

Keypad shows the initcap but it is disable.

How I enter the capital words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextInputTraitsProtocol has a property called autocapitalizationType. Setting this to autocapitalizationTypeNone, makes caps lock key inactive. probably u are setting this property to none

Comment: it"s not works,I have taken UITextInputTraitsProtocol after that itried to do  "[textfield setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizatioTypeNone] "....But it"S not work.

Comment: don't set autocapitalizationType to none try -    [textfield setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters]

Answer (score 0):

**in iOS 6**

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
```